# How to find the value of $\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x\cos{x^2}}-e^{x}}{x^5}$

Tags: limits

How to find the exact value of the following limit?

$\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x\cos{x^2}}-e^{x}}{x^5}$

Comment: I believe that using L'Hospital's rule several times will give you a nice result.

Comment: @AndrewStelzer And yet, there are sooo simpler approaches...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\cos x^2=1-\frac{x^4}{2}+o(x^4)$$
so
$$e^{x\cos x^2} = e^{x-\frac{x^5}{2}+o(x^5)} = e^xe^{-\frac{x^5}{2}+o(x^5)}$$
therefore 
$$\frac{e^{x\cos x^2}-e^x}{x^5} = e^x\frac{e^{-\frac{x^5}{2}+o(x^5)}-1}{x^5} \sim e^x\frac{-\frac{x^5}{2}}{x^5} \xrightarrow[x\to0]{}-\frac{1}{2}$$
using $e^u-1\sim u$ when $u\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\dfrac{e^{x\cos x^2}-e^x}{x^5}=e^x\cdot\dfrac{e^{x(\cos x^2-1)}-1}{x^5}$$

$$\dfrac{e^{x(\cos x^2-1)}-1}{x^5}=\dfrac{e^{x(\cos x^2-1)}-1}{x(\cos x^2-1)}\cdot\dfrac{x(\cos x^2-1)}{x^5}$$

$$\dfrac{\cos x^2-1}{x^4}=-\left(\dfrac{\sin x^2}{x^2}\right)^2\cdot\dfrac1{(1+\cos x^2)}$$

Now use $\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{e^h-1}h=1$  and $\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin y}y=1$